# How to select data from database in listbox inside a form view in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to get the data from database in listbox which is placed inside the form view control i have passed selected value from gridview as parameter in both form view control and listbox. Form view control working properly but can not fetch data in listbox.

Query that i have use

```
   SELECT mst_Tag.tagId, mst_Tag.Tag_Name FROM mst_Tag INNER JOIN Post2Tag ON mst_Tag.tagId = Post2Tag.Tag_Id WHERE (Post2Tag.Post_Id = @Post_Id)

@Post_Id= gridview1.SelectedValue
```

Comment: Can you please specify what query you are firing for the same..??

Comment: Can you show "listbox" insertion in page, and the query returning values from DB? I'm afraid that you doesn't populate the listbox's DataSource with values. (Or values are in wrong format)

Comment: I am using the default Datasource and query builder from asp.net.

Comment: As you don't have code example, maybe you will fin this answer usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333961/asp-net-populate-a-listbox-without-a-postback

Comment: @meorfi the query is working properly while testing it in query builder but at run time it can not find the value of gridview`s selected value

Comment: make sure, from GRIDVIEW you get the right 'Id' which you want to pass to Server

Comment: @Bhupendra show the code snippet from asp page, and the logic

Comment: i have edit the question that might help you to finding out the problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is SP :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MenuAction__Sel_UnSel]
        -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    (
        @MenuId INT
    )
    AS
    BEGIN
        -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Insert statements for procedure here

        ---- Unselected Record

        Select  a.Action,'DB' AS DML_TYP
          from dbo.MenuAction_m a
         Where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Menu_d AS b WHERE B.Action=A.Action AND B.MenuId=@MenuId);

         ---- Selected Record

       Select  c.MenuId,a.Action,'DB' AS DML_TYP
          from dbo.MenuAction_m a,Menu_d as c 
         WHERE a.Action=c.Action and  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Menu_d AS b WHERE B.Action=A.Action AND b.MenuId=@MenuId and c.Action=b.Action and c.MenuId=b.MenuId) ;
    END
```

This is Design Page :

```
<tr class="odd">
                                        <td class="column1">
                                            <b>UnSelected Items</b>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <b>Selected Items</b>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="column1">
                                            <telerik:RadListBox ID="RadLstUnselectedIns" runat="server" AllowTransfer="true"
                                                AutoPostBackOnTransfer="true" Height="120px" SelectionMode="Multiple" TransferToID="RadLstselectedIns">
                                                <ButtonSettings TransferButtons="All" />
                                            </telerik:RadListBox>
                                            <telerik:RadToolTip ID="radToolTipRadLstUnselected" runat="server" RelativeTo="Element"
                                                Height="40px" Text="This Actions are not Selected!" TargetControlID="RadLstUnselectedIns"
                                                Position="MiddleRight" EnableAriaSupport="true">
                                            </telerik:RadToolTip>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <telerik:RadListBox ID="RadLstselectedIns" runat="server" Height="120px">
                                            </telerik:RadListBox>
                                            <telerik:RadToolTip ID="radToolTipRadLstselectedIns" runat="server" RelativeTo="Element"
                                                Height="40px" Text="This Actions are  Selected!" TargetControlID="RadLstselectedIns"
                                                Position="MiddleRight" EnableAriaSupport="true">
                                            </telerik:RadToolTip>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
```

THis is Code Behind :

```
   protected void frmview_ItemInserting(object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
        {

            RadListBox lstUnselected = (RadListBox)frmview.FindControl("RadLstUnselectedIns");
            DataSet dsData = objMenuMBAL.getAction(0);
            DataTable dtDataunsel = dsData.Tables[0];
            if (dtDataunsel.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lstUnselected.DataSource = dtDataunsel;
                lstUnselected.DataTextField = "Action";
                lstUnselected.DataValueField = "Action";
                lstUnselected.DataBind();
            }
            RadListBox lstselected = (RadListBox)frmview.FindControl("RadLstselectedIns");
        }
```

Comment: As its not free ,i can not use telerik control or can u suggest me how to use this control free??

Comment: U CAN ALSO USE THE SIMPLE LIST BOX.THIS CODE ALSO BE USED IN SIMPLE TEXTBOX

Answer (score 2):

protected void frmview_ItemInserting(object snd, FormViewInsertEventArgs format)
        {

```
        RadListBox lst = (RadListBox)frmview.FindControl("RadLstUnselectedIns");
        DataSet dsData = objMenuMBAL.getAction(0);
        DataTable dtDataunsel = dsData.Tables[0];
        if (dtDataunsel.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            lst.DataSource = dtDataunsel;
            lst.DataTextField = "Action";
            lst.DataValueField = "Action";
            lst.DataBind();
        }
        RadListBox lstselected = (RadListBox)frmview.FindControl("RadLstselectedIns");
    }
```